# Puppeteer - waitForResponse() timeout, but page.on('response') finds response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I'm trying to get an XHR response from a webpage. I found the

```js
await page.waitForResponse(url);
```

or

```js
await page.waitForResponse((res) => {
  if (res.url() === myUrl) return true;
});
```

method, but it always timeout for the url response I'm trying to get.

However, if I set

```js
page.on('response', (res) => {
  if (res.url() === myUrl) {
    // do what I want with the response
  }
})
```

the correct response is found and I can retrive the data.

After some debugging, seems like waitForResponse() isn't returning any XHR req/res.

Any ideias?

**EDIT:**
Example. For this case, its required to use `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth` and `puppeteer-extra` package, otherwise, this URL will return status code '403':

```js
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import UserAgent from 'user-agents';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import { Page } from 'puppeteer';

const wantedUrl = 'https://www.nike.com.br/DataLayer/dataLayer';

const workingFunction = async (page: Page) => {
    let reqCount = 0;
    let resCount = 0;

    page.on('request', req => {
        reqCount++;
        if (req.url() == wantedUrl) {
            console.log('The request I need: ', req.url());
            console.log(reqCount);
        }
    });
    page.on('response', async res => {
        resCount++;
        if (res.url() == wantedUrl) {
            console.log('The response I need:', await res.json());
            console.log(resCount);
        }
    });

    await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-sb-dunk-low-pro-unissex-153-169-229-284741', {
        timeout: 0,
    });
};

const notWorkingFunction = async (page: Page) => {
    let resCount = 0;
    await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-sb-dunk-low-pro-unissex-153-169-229-284741');
    const res = await page.waitForResponse(
        res => {
            resCount++;
            console.log(res.url());
            console.log(resCount);
            if (res.url() === wantedUrl) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        { timeout: 0 }
    );

    return res;
};

(async () => {
    puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const userAgent = new UserAgent({ deviceCategory: 'desktop' });
    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.random().toString());

    try {
        // workingFunction(page);
        const res = await notWorkingFunction(page);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason the `page.on` version works is because it sets the request/response handlers *before performing navigation*. On the other hand, the `waitForResponse` version waits until the `"load"` event fires (`page.goto()`'s default resolution point), and only then starts tracking responses with the call to `page.waitForResponse`. [MDN says of the `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event):

> The `load` event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event), which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.

Based on this, we can infer that by the time the `load` event fires and the `waitForResponse` function finally starts listening to traffic, it's already missed the desired response, so it just waits forever!

The solution is to create the promise for `page.waitForResponse` before (or at the same time as) the `goto` call such that no traffic is missed when you kick off navigation.

I also suggest using `"domcontentloaded"` on the `goto` call. `"domcontentloaded"` is underused in Puppeteer -- there's no sense in waiting for all resources to arrive when you're just looking for one. The default `"load"` or often-used `"networkidleN"` settings are better for use cases like screenshotting the page where you want the whole thing to look like it does as a user would see it. To be clear, this isn't the fix to the problem, just an optimization, and it's not too apparent from the docs which is suitable when.

Here's a minimal example (I used JS, not TS):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra"); // ^3.2.3
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth"); // ^2.9.0
const UserAgent = require("user-agents"); // ^1.0.958

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const userAgent = new UserAgent({deviceCategory: "desktop"});
  await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.random().toString());
  const url = "https://www.nike.com.br/tenis-nike-sb-dunk-low-pro-unissex-153-169-229-284741";
  const wantedUrl = "https://www.nike.com.br/DataLayer/dataLayer";
  const [res] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse(res => res.url() === wantedUrl, {timeout: 90_000}),
    page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}),
  ]);
  console.log(await res.json());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Comment: Great, thank you. How could I have found this myself? Does Puppeteer docs infer anything about this? And when you say "__To be clear, this isn't the fix to the problem, just an optimization...__", are you refering to using "domcontentloaded"?

Comment: For figuring it out yourself, I just played with it and was pre-aware of the fact that `goto` by default waits for external resources before resolving, as well as the `Promise.all` idiom used elsewhere in Puppeteer, like [using `waitForNavigaton`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options). Yeah, the `"domcontentloaded"` option is just a matter of not waiting for anything other than the response you want and the DOM content, rather than all resources. If you leave it as `"load"`, it will work but it might be slower (you'd have to benchmark).